# Wrong indent in c-mode and c++-mode

Tags: c++, align, c, indentation

In my coding style tabs used to indent and spaces for align. I've configure Emacs for this, but some times emacs places 4 spaces instead of tabulation in some blocks of code. If can be fixed by reindenting whole block (beetwin `{}`), but some times this way not work too.
How can I fix it?
PS `.emacs` here http://pastebin.com/c2pcD79k

Comment: It seems like you are having some advices that set `indent-tab-mode` to nil. Try commenting those out.

Comment: Also, you have some `setq`s for other modes that set `indent-tab-mode` to `nil`. Try using `setq-local` instead. And fyi, you can combine `setq`s into one sexp like: `(setq-local tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode t)`

Comment: @nanny you can't combine `setq-local` like that, [yet](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-03/msg00448.html).

Comment: @npostavs Thanks, obviously I should test things out before I post them.